# Namespace, class and compiler order

Tags: c++, class, header, namespaces

I'm experiencing with OpenGL and I built and edit a Vector3 header that works perfectly that works with struct `Vector3` but the problem starts when I tried create a `Vector3 zero = Vector3(0,0,0)` variable, the compiler doesn't let me build due to the compiling order so I copied a new Vector3 library from Internet and I get this error: `"Vector3 does not name a type"`. I suppose is cause the order of compiling, I'll share where I get the error and the libraries. First this is the 2 files I'm using http://leetnightshade.com/c-vector3-class I'm only using Vector3.cpp and Vector3.h, and this code is made from me and is where I get the error (this is a header file called by the main.cpp file named GameObject.h):

```
#include "Vector3.h"

GLfloat cube[] =
{
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
};

GLfloat Space3D_X[] =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f, -100,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 100
};

GLfloat Space3D_Y[] =
{
    -100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};

typedef struct GameObject
{
    int ID, parent;
    Vector3 position;  ///<<<--------------------------HERE I GET THE ERROR VECTOR3 DOES NOT NAME A TYPE
    Quaternion rotation;
};

struct GameObject GameObjects[65536];

class Natives
{
    public:
        int GameObjectsCount = 0;
        inline int CreateCube (Vector3 _position, Quaternion _rotation, int _parent)
        {
            GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].ID = GameObjectsCount;
            GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].parent = _parent;
            GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].position = _position;
            GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].rotation = _rotation;
            GameObjectsCount ++;
            return GameObjectsCount-1;
        }
        inline void SetGameObjectParent (int _gameObject, int _parent)
        {
            Vector3 _tempPos = GameObjects[_gameObject].position;
            Quaternion _tempRot = GameObjects[_gameObject].rotation;
            GameObjects[_gameObject].parent = _parent;                                               /*** ATTACH GM TO OTHER GM WITHOUT CHANGE POSITION ***/
            GameObjects[_gameObject].position.x = -(GameObjects[_parent].position.x - _tempPos.x);   /*** IF YOU WANT TO ATTACH IT CHAING POSITION JUST ***/
            GameObjects[_gameObject].position.z = -(GameObjects[_parent].position.z - _tempPos.z);   /***     OVERWRITE THE PARENT WITH OOP SYNTAX      ***/
            GameObjects[_gameObject].rotation.rx = _tempRot.rx;
            GameObjects[_gameObject].rotation.ry =  _tempRot.ry;
            GameObjects[_gameObject].rotation.rz =  _tempRot.rz;
        }
};

Natives native;
```

Focus on the 4 lines of struct GameObject that is where I get the error in the Vector3 position; line. I think I explain myself correctly. I made a scheme if you don't understand well http://gyazo.com/77189bef5576b047de5271f1b7d2d881. Thanks for Read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Vector3` library you link uses namespace `_Warp`, so you should use it this way:

```
_Warp::Vector3 position;
```

**PS:** Be wary of any third-party library that uses reserved names as identifiers, because the writers may not know what they are doing. `_Warp` is a reserved name for the compiler (it starts with `_`  plus uppercase) and should not be used by library or program code.

Comment: Thanks you so much it works! So the only way to define a variable as Vector3 is _Warp::Vector3? Or I can make a shortcut to avoid the _Warp?

Comment: @tonyperez: You can also write `use namespace _Warp;` just after the `#include "Vector3.h"` line. But it is considered bad practice to `use namespace` inside a header file.

Comment: So, The only way to remove is that way and is a bad idea, no more ways?

Comment: @tonyperez: Well, you can edit out the `namespace _Warp {` lines from the original source code, if the license allows it (be wary of shared code without a license...). Anyway I wouldn't bother too much about it, just get used to the namespace thing and you will learn to appreciate it.